# I want words after first full stop in a column containing text using R

Tags: r

I want text from second sentence.

```
text="I need to go to mall today. I want to purchase clothes. Also, I want to buy shoes."
```

Expected result:

```
I want to purchase clothes. Also, I want to buy shoes.
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility with `strsplit()`:

```
sapply(strsplit(text, ". ", fixed = TRUE), 
       function(x) paste(x[2:length(x)], collapse = ". "))

[1] "I want to purchase clothes. Also, I want to buy shoes."
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `stringr::str_match` to capture everything after first dot.

```
stringr::str_match(text, "\\.(.*)")[, 2]
#[1] " I want to purchase clothes. Also, I want to buy shoes."
```

`[, 2]` is to get the capture group.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` with `sub` to match characters that are not a `.` followed by a `.` and space if any, replace with blanks (`""`)

```
sub("^[^.]+\\.\\s*", "", text)
#[1] "I want to purchase clothes. Also, I want to buy shoes."
```

and the equivalent option in `tidyverse` would be

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(text, "^[^.]+\\.\\s*", "")
#[1] "I want to purchase clothes. Also, I want to buy shoes."
```